# IntellijIDEA: synchronization of updatings in the pom-file and external libraries

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

I updated the version of library through the pom-file. During compilation all necessary jar for the new version were downloaded from a repository. But in IntellijIDEA the corresponding external libraries weren't updated. I removed in IDE these libraries manually, in hope that on their place will appear new, but occurred nothing (simply the project ceased to see library).
How to update external libraries?
Thanks in advance.

UPD:
The third-party library which is used from Maven means. Its use is adjusted through the pom-file. When it was declared, after the first compilation it was downloaded from a repository, and the corresponding external libraries were automatically added to IDE. The problem described above appeared after attempt of updating of library.

Comment: maybe this post helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19444471/intellij-idea-how-to-synchronize-project-libraries-with-dependencies-in-pom-xml?rq=1

Comment: Thanx! I saw this early, but my problem other.

Comment: MAven projects won't include external jar files into its classpath. You have to install them in your local repository manually and then refer them in the pom.xml file.

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/q/4955635/2557818

Comment: @RajaAnbazhagan: I specified a situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a right Click on the project: Maven->Reimport.