# Maven - what the correct scope for JDBC jar files?

Tags: java, maven, jdbc, scope

For my development station, I need my project to "see" the JDBC drivers. But when I deploy the project to the server, if the JDBC drivers are in the /lib folder they'll cause the container to misbehave.

I tried setting the `<scope>provided</scope>` to the drivers I don't want to package on my .war file, but I can't get my IDE to run the project.

What's a correct scope to declare the JDBC drivers on `pom.xml` so they don't get packaged for deploy and I can work with them on my development station? `<scope>runtime</scope>`?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: what's the IDE? likely you need to tell the IDE which drivers to use for the app (and correctly tell the pom that these are not to be packaged - i.e. provided)

Comment: IDE is Spring ToolSource

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer for your question is: you should use `provided` scope.

Why not `runtime`? Let's check Maven docs:

**provided**

> This is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime. For example, when building a web application for the Java Enterprise Edition, you would set the dependency on the Servlet API and related Java EE APIs to scope provided because the web container provides those classes. This scope is only available on the compilation and test classpath, and is not transitive.

**runtime**

> This scope indicates that the dependency is not required for compilation, but is for execution. It is in the runtime and test classpaths, but not the compile classpath.

So, Maven may not expose `runtime` scoped dependencies in compile's classpath, thus you won't be able to use them in you code directly. However, the code like `Class.forName("class.from.runtime.Scope")` will compile ok.

I guess the problem is your IDE which didn't seized `pom.xml` changes. Usually, this problem is fixed by "cleaning cache" or "updating" / "syncing" your project. Here is how to do this in [Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20546962/750510) and [IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19444471/750510).

Comment: The current revision of this answer differs from the opinion of [baeldung.com](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-dependency-scopes#3-runtime) (scope: runtime) and I would be pleased if someone reviews this answer.

Comment: The OP said that the drivers are in his `lib` folder. I.e. they are provided by the container and it is not required to pack them in the distributable package. Thus, the scope should be `provided`.